# How to make user auto login in MOODLE

Tags: php, api, curl, moodle, moodle-api

I have a portal called xyz.com and a Moodle site called yzx.com. I have some users on both sites, which have same usernames and password. What I want is when a user logs in on non-Moodle site called xyz.com, he should auto login to the same user on yzx.com i.e moodle site.

Please help me how can I make curl or API request to moodle so it auto-logins on the current browser. Moodle has function user_login($username,$pass) but don't know how to use it as I am new to moodle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution, and to help others too, I am posting this answer myself. You can use Moodles function throughout the folder of moodle, via that I created the api.

```
<?php 


require('config.php');
$name=$_REQUEST['username'];
$password=$_REQUEST['password'];
$dashboard = $CFG->wwwroot;
$user = authenticate_user_login($name, $password);
if(complete_user_login($user))
{   
    $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/login/logout.php?sesskey=".$user->sesskey;
       echo json_encode(['user'=>$user,'logout'=>$actual_link],true); die;

}
else
{
   echo "not login"; die;
}



?>
```

create this file anywhere in Moodle, I created in the root of moodle and hit it using curl, with get or post parameters as username and password.

Comment: Can i login with above code using password having encrypted with hashing and directly collected from database based on username?

Comment: Yes you need to check it well its four years back I used Moodle.

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to do(auto-login) is not recommended(can cause security risk) when you have 2 different domains like xyz.com and yzx.com. It can be achieved if you have sub-domain mechanism.

Let say your primary site is running on xyz.com and moodle on moodle.xyz.com then when user login to xyz.com you can create a cookie for domain like `*.xyz.com` and when you navigate to moodle sub-domain(with some modification) it will read the cookie and auto-login. Cookies can be shared across primary and sub-domains but not across different domains. We need to ensure the cookie name is same or might need to modify some code in moodle to achieve this.

Hope this help!